# SSAS Stored Procedure throwing permission

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssas, sqlclient, system.data

I am getting the error

```
Execution of the managed stored procedure 'mystoredprocedure' failed with the following error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.Request for the permission of type 'System."Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='bunchofgarbagenumbers' failed..
```

This is what comes up when a user tries to access the cube through excel. Currently there is cube member permissions based on their territories which can be found in sql tables. My dll connects to a sql server and gets the data it needs from there and forms it into an mdx set.

It's been working smooth for the past few weeks until today where users are getting this error message. The rest of IT has reported to me no changes have been made to the requirements for the connection string (which I confirmed by  logging in using its credentials in Sql Server Management Studio) Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Thanks,
Ethan

Comment: You mention a dll, could this be anything to do with http://weblogs.asp.net/mjarguello/archive/2011/04/25/visual-studio-2010-crashes-with-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation.aspx?

Comment: No, the dll is something I created, I'm not having any problems with visual studios 2010 crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, the dll was redeployed, but when it was redeployed, the properties inside of bids for the dll were on safe, not giving it any external server access.